# How to make the script to return with specified value in Perl debugger?

Tags: perl

I tried various ways, but none works...

```
  DB<4> T
. = main::t() called from file `dbg' line 6
  DB<4> return;

  DB<5> T
. = main::t() called from file `dbg' line 6
  DB<5> return 1;

  DB<6> T
. = main::t() called from file `dbg' line 6
  DB<6> eval('return')

  DB<7> T
. = main::t() called from file `dbg' line 6
```

The point is I don't want the subsequent code to be run, just return with specified value.

So it's not `r`.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously ghetto but you could wait until you pop back out of routine and then manually set the lvalue before proceeding in the calling routine.